# Setting Session Variable from Form

Tags: php, forms, session

Is it possible to set a session variable from a radio button?
This is what I have so far:

```
<form action="process.php" method"post">
<input type="radio" name="number" id="number" value="1" /> 1 
<input type="radio" name="number" id="number" value="2" /> 2 
<input type="radio" name="number" id="number" value="3" /> 3 <br />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And then for my process.php:

```
<?php 
session_start();
session_register ("number");
$_SESSION['number'] = $_POST['number'];
echo "Number = ". $_SESSION['number'];
?>
```

I have the echo "Number =  " in there just to test and make sure the variable is being set, but it still seems to be coming back blank.

I am really confused. Thank you for your help :-)

Answer (score 4):

You are missing `=` in here:

```
method"post"
```

Should be:

```
method="post"
```

---

#### Note

You have a couple of more problems:

The `id` should always be unique per element per page

```
<input type="radio" name="number" id="number1" value="1" /> 1 
<input type="radio" name="number" id="number2" value="2" /> 2 
<input type="radio" name="number" id="number3" value="3" /> 3 <br />
```

Avoid using `session_register` function because it is deprecated, eg remove below line:

```
session_register ("number");
```

Comment: Is it possible to get a session variable from the unique id? E.g. `$_SESSION['number1'];`?

Comment: @Amyunimus: what do you mean by `unique id` here? As I see, `number1`, `number2` ... are in `html` form

Comment: Does `$_SESSION[variable]` always grab the value by the `name` of the input, or would it be possible to get the value from the `id` of the input (when it differs from `name`, as in your example.)?

Answer (score 1):

session_register is deprecated so no need to use it.

just

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['number'] = $_POST['number'];
echo "Number = ". $_SESSION['number'];
?>
```

should do the trick.

also your form action is messed up:

`<form action="process.php" method"post">`

should be

`<form action="process.php" method="post">`

Answer (score 0):

`method"post"` should be `method="post"`. This is why it sends as a GET request, therefore `$_POST['number']` will be undefined.

And yes, do not use `session_register()`.